# Filtering Dataframe based on Multiple Date Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm working with the following DataFrame:

```
id  slotTime    EDD EDD-10M
0   1000000101068957    2021-05-12  2021-12-26  2021-02-26
1   1000000100849718    2021-03-20  2021-04-05  2020-06-05
2   1000000100849718    2021-03-20  2021-04-05  2020-06-05
3   1000000100849718    2021-03-20  2021-04-05  2020-06-05
4   1000000100849718    2021-03-20  2021-04-05  2020-06-05
```

I would like to only keep the rows where the `slotTime` is between `EDD-10M` and `EDD`:

`df['EDD-10M'] < df['slotTime'] < df['EDD']]`

I have tried using the following method:

`df.loc[df[df['slotTime'] < df['EDD']] & df[df['EDD-10M'] < df['slotTime']]]`

However it yields the following error

`TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Please Advise.

*To replicate the above DataFrame use the below snippet:*

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

df = { 
  'id': {0: 1000000101068957,
  1: 1000000100849718,
  2: 1000000100849718,
  3: 1000000100849718,
  4: 1000000100849718,
  5: 1000000100849718,
  6: 1000000100849718,
  7: 1000000100849718,
  8: 1000000100849718,
  9: 1000000100849718},
  'EDD': {0: Timestamp('2021-12-26 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2021-04-05 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2021-04-05 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2021-04-05 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2021-04-05 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2021-04-05 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2021-04-05 00:00:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2021-04-05 00:00:00'),
  8: Timestamp('2021-04-05 00:00:00'),
  9: Timestamp('2021-04-05 00:00:00')},
 'EDD-10M': {0: Timestamp('2021-02-26 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2020-06-05 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2020-06-05 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2020-06-05 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2020-06-05 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2020-06-05 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2020-06-05 00:00:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2020-06-05 00:00:00'),
  8: Timestamp('2020-06-05 00:00:00'),
  9: Timestamp('2020-06-05 00:00:00')},
 'slotTime': {0: Timestamp('2021-05-12 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2021-03-20 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2021-03-20 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2021-03-20 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2021-03-20 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2021-03-20 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2021-03-20 00:00:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2021-03-20 00:00:00'),
  8: Timestamp('2021-03-20 00:00:00'),
  9: Timestamp('2021-03-20 00:00:00')}}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you just need to group your sides

```
df[(df['slotTime'] < df['EDD']) & (df['EDD-10M'] < df['slotTime'])]
```

otherwise order of operations tries to & things first and it all falls apart

alternatively you may wish to use the .between operator (assuming you have a datetime series

```
df[df['slotTime'].between(df['EDD'],df['EDD-10M'])]
```

Comment: Tried running your answer and it yielded `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: oops unballanced brackets... ill fix it

Comment: The first one works great! but the second one returns an empty df

Answer (score 1):

you can use between() method someone already answered you or try like this

```
df.loc[(df['EDD-10M'] < df['slotTime']) & (df['slotTime'] < df['EDD'])]
```

you should use ( and ) multiple conditions

Answer (score 1):

You can this by using [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df.query("(slotTime < EDD) & (`EDD-10M` < slotTime)")
```